# SED search and replace more than 1 pattern if matched line

Tags: bash, sed

How to search and replace multiple patterns for a matched section in a file?
I tried this

```
sed '/pattern1,pattern2/s/string1/replace1/g;s/string2/replace2/g' file
```

But it will ignore the pattern1,pattern2 section and do search and replace for the whole file for my second search and replace.

Comment: `/test/{command1;command2}`

Comment: make an example pls.

Answer (score 0):

Curlies.

For the record, this is for [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), which you appear to be using. For other versions/portability, replace the semicolons with newlines.

Also `/pattern1,pattern2/` is only searching for literally "pattern1,pattern2" as a single string.

If I read this right, you want to do some substitutions on lines that have both `pattern1` and `pattern2`, though not necessarily in any relative placement. In that case:

```
sed '
  /pattern1/ { 
    /pattern2/ { 
      s/string1/replace1/g;
      s/string2/replace2/g;
    }
  }
' file
```

I spaced it out for readability, but you could smash it all back into one line if you really wanted to.

If you *know* `pattern1` is always before `pattern2` then you could use

```
sed '/pattern1.*pattern2/ { 
  s/string1/replace1/g; s/string2/replace2/g;
}' file
```

But if they could be in reversed order, use the first `sed`.

Also...maybe we could get a sample file to test against? These are just typed off the cuff, but if you had provided example data I would actually use it to test them first before submitting something that might have a typo or a logic flaw. Just a suggestion. People will be more likely to be thorough if you don't make *them* genberate all the pieces, lol

Comment: semicolons are ok in [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings, that is all. Assuming based on the surrounding description that by `/pattern1,pattern2/` you actually meant `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` then with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
awk '
/pattern1/ { f=1 }
f {
    gsub(/string1/,"replace1")
    gsub(/string2/,"replace2")
}
/pattern2/ { f=0 }
1' file
```

Comment: If they did mean that, doesn't sed just need to be told to group the operations:  `sed '/p1/,/p2/ { s/s1/r1/; s/s2/r2/; }' file` ?

Comment: @jhnc that depends on the version of sed and whether or not you want the start and/or end lines included in the substitutions. With the awk version you just swap the order of the 3 blocks to get whatever behavior you want, with sed it's a more complicated issue.

Comment: Did I use nonstandard syntax somewhere? Agreed that awk is more powerful, though sed is often more concise for simple problems such as this one

Comment: idk, my experience is that almost anything other than s/old/new only works in some seds so I'd assume thjere's something there that only works in some seds. Maybe try it on the default sed on Solaris or MacOS/BSD sed - those frequently don't behave the same as other seds?